# Python - NumPy Array Logical XOR operation byte wise

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am reading an image via Pillow and converting it to a numpy array.

```
        A = numpy.asarray(Image.open(
            ImageNameA).convert("L"))
        B = numpy.asarray(Image.open(
            ImageNameB).convert("L"))

print A
[[255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 ..., 
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]
 [255 255 255 ..., 255 255 255]]
```

Now when I do any logical operation on these 2 numpy arrays, I get it in form of 'True' and 'False'

```
Answer = numpy.logical_xor(A,B)

print  numpy.logical_xor(A,C)
[[False False False ..., False False False]
 [False False False ..., False False False]
 [False False False ..., False False False]
 ..., 
 [False False False ..., False False False]
 [False False False ..., False False False]
 [False False False ..., False False False]]
```

My image processing functions cant work with True, False ... How can i get an image in form of 0 , 255 (in bytes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the question title, I suppose the function you meant to use is actualy `numpy.bitwise_xor` it will output arrays in the 0-255 range as you expect.

`logical_xor` treats all number above 1 as `True` and 0 as `False` and always outputs a boolean array (only 0s and 1s).

Comment: Also note that the infix operator for the bitwise exclusive or of numpy arrays is `^`.